# JAVA - Creating a Row of Colored Boxes with Loops?

Tags: java, graphics, nested-loops

I'm a beginner with graphics, as well as Java all together. It seems that no matter what I do, this program is not working! :( Anyway, the goal is to "Use nested loops, Graphics, and Math.random() to print out the square pattern"
The pattern is 30x30 squares next to each other in 14 rows by 20 columns. 
Here is my code so far:

```js
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Canvas;

class ColoredBoxes extends Canvas
{
 public ColoredBoxes()
 {
  setBackground(Color.BLACK);
 }

 public void paint( Graphics window )
 {
  window.setColor(Color.RED);
  window.setFont(new Font("TAHOMA",Font.BOLD,12));
    window.drawString("**Fun Fact: I hate snow.**", 20, 40 );
    window.drawString("Drawing boxes with nested loops ", 20, 80 );
    //private static final int WIDTH = 800;
     //private static final int HEIGHT = 600;
     //Boxes: 20 Across, 14 Down


    drawBoxes(window);
 }

 public void drawBoxes(Graphics window)
 {
  //nested loops to draw the pretty boxes
  //int drawRow = 1;
  //int drawCol = 1;
  int c1 = (int)(Math.random()*256);
  int c2 = (int)(Math.random()*256);
  int c3 = (int)(Math.random()*256);
  Color random = new Color (c1,c2,c3);
  int dS = 30; //Distance from the side (left)
  int dT = 100; //Distance from the top
  int x = 30; //Width
  int y = 30; //Height
  for(int drawRow = 1; drawRow <= 14; drawRow++)
  {
      for(int drawCol = 1; drawCol <= 20; drawCol++)
      {
          
          window.setColor(Color.white);
          window.fillRect(dS, dT, x, y);
          window.setColor(Color.black);
          window.drawRect(dS, dT, x, y);
          System.out.println();
         
          dS = dS+y; 
       
      }
      dT = dT+x;
      
      
  }   
   
   

}
}
```

Each square should also be a different, random color. What did I do wrong?
Thank you so much :)

Answer (score 2):

Start by taking a look through [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/) and [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html) for details about painting actually works.

You don't control the paint process, this means that painting may occur at any time for any reason, many of which are outside of your control.  This means, that each time `drawBoxes` is called, you are generating new colors.

Painting is also made up of a chain of method calls, which helps provide better customisation opportunities, but you are breaking this paint chain by not calling `super.paint` first.

What I would do is first create a `List` or array of colors, which represent each individual cell in your grid.  I would use this each time `paint` was called to ensure that the painting was consistent

[image: Pretty Grid]

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class ColoredBoxes {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new ColoredBoxes();
    }

    public ColoredBoxes() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public static class TestPane extends JPanel {

        protected static final int ROWS = 14;
        protected static final int COLS = 20;
        protected static final int BOX_SIZE = 30;

        private List<Color> colors;

        public TestPane() {
            int length = ROWS * COLS;
            colors = new ArrayList<>(length);
            for (int index = 0; index < length; index++) {
                int c1 = (int) (Math.random() * 255);
                int c2 = (int) (Math.random() * 255);
                int c3 = (int) (Math.random() * 255);
                colors.add(new Color(c1, c2, c3));
            }
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(COLS * BOX_SIZE, ROWS * BOX_SIZE);
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();

            int xOffset = (getWidth() - (COLS * BOX_SIZE)) / 2;
            int yOffset = (getHeight() - (ROWS * BOX_SIZE)) / 2;

            System.out.println("...");
            for (int row = 0; row < ROWS; row++) {
                for (int col = 0; col < COLS; col++) {
                    int index = (row * COLS) + col;
                    g2d.setColor(colors.get(index));
                    g2d.fillRect(xOffset + (col * BOX_SIZE), 
                                    yOffset + (row * BOX_SIZE), 
                                    BOX_SIZE, BOX_SIZE);
                }
            }
            g2d.dispose();
        }

    }

}
```

**Updated**

The basic problem revolves around how you are calculating the row/col position for each cell and the misuse of the `Graphics#draw/fillRectangle` method.

While you could simply increment the `x/y` position of each grid within the `for-loop`, a simpler approach would be to simply calculate them based on your current `row/col`

```
int xOffset = 50;
int yOffset = 100;
for (int drawRow = 0; drawRow < 14; drawRow++) {
    for (int drawCol = 0; drawCol < 20; drawCol++) {
        int x = drawCol * 30 + xOffset;
        int y = (drawRow * 30) + yOffset;
```

The next issue is the misuse of `Graphics#draw/fillRect`.  The JavaDocs state that

> public abstract void fillRect(int x,
>           int y,
>           int width,
>           int height)
>  Fills the specified rectangle. The left and right edges of the rectangle are at x and x + width - 1. The
>   top and bottom edges are at y and y + height - 1. The resulting
>   rectangle covers an area width pixels wide by height pixels tall. The
>   rectangle is filled using the graphics context's current
>   color.
>  **Parameters:**
>  x - the x coordinate of the
>   rectangle to be filled.
>  y - the y coordinate of the rectangle to
>   be filled.
>  width - the width of the rectangle to be filled.
>   height - the height of the rectangle to be filled.

This means that last two parameters should be `30, 30`, not what ever you're currently passing to them.

Also you MUST call `super.paint(window);` before you perform any custom painting.

Comment: Thats awesome but unfortuatley I cannot change the names of the classes :(

Comment: There is nothing stopping me, but I'll loose points on my final mark for this lab.

Comment: So, use the concept and put into your class.  The intention of the provided code is for demonstration, you're going to have to make it fit within your needs...

Comment: Does not help. I've never seen graphics in java before this day, I have to stick to what I was given. I have no idea what half of what you wrote is, and I still dont know what I did wrong to begin with.

Comment: Then we're not the people you need to talking to, if this is a lab, you need to be checking with your tutor...

Comment: Also, using `java.awt.Canvas` is not a good place to start, the AWT library is 15+ years out of date and generally remains to support the Swing API...

Comment: Then I'm not sure what this site is for if I cant know what I did wrong or where I should aim to fix it in a way I am able to understand. Perhaps it is not welcome to beginners. And no, I will have no contact with the "tutor," I will not see her or be able to contact her till April.

Comment: Again, I was just given the empty classes. I have no idea what the java.awt.Canvas is, nor was I taught.

Comment: I cannot seem to find any help here. Thank you for trying but I'll terminate the account and go elsewhere.

Comment: @BriannaNicole That's a shame, cause I've updated the question ... and 5 minutes with the JavaDocs and the [2D Graphics tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/) would probably have answered the majority of your questions...

Comment: Its ok, I got help from another site. It was the nested loops.

Comment: @BriannaNicole With respect, if you've modified the code, consider updating the original question, double posting generally isn't encouraged

Comment: It does not matter. There was no help with the question here, but if it pleases the mods then sure.

Comment: @BriannaNicole Well, I guess when the student is ready, the teacher will appear, best of luck